# SNS SQS - Not receiving messages that were pushed to queue from SNS topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SNS topic `TestTopic`, I have an SQS queue `newtestqueue-ev`, I have a java application that will push messages to either the topic or the queue. I have a Java application that reads from the queue.

When I push to the queue via java app / aws console  I receive the message in my application. When I push a message to the topic which has the SQS queue as a subscriber I do not receive any message.

Here is permission added to the SQS queue

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:<accountnum>:newtestqueue-ev/SQSDefaultPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "sidNum",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:<accountNum>:newtestqueue-ev",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:<accountNum>:TestTopic"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have encryption enabled on the queue using the default key `alias/aws/sqs` and encryption on the sns topic using the default `alias/aws/sns`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use the default kms key on the SNS queue, you need to create a new one and add this to it

```
{
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
                "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
             },
         "Action": [
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:Decrypt"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but I found a solution that didn't require a custom key with permissions. There are apparently two default keys that can be used with SQS, one is "SSE-KMS" and the other is "SSE-SQS"

When I had it set to SSE-KMS the notifications were not arriving in the queue. When I switched to SSE-SQS and made no other changes, the notifications arrived in the queue. I'm building with CDK, so when I was defining the queue, I changed

```
encryption: QueueEncryption.KMS_MANAGED
```

to

```
encryption: QueueEncryption.SQS_MANAGED
```

[image: Screenshot showing both encryption options]